# Create view by performing multiple sums on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MYSQL database and I need to merge them in a view.
On both table I must perfom some math in order to get the right result and I must order them by the same day.

The first table is like the one below and it's called `chiusure`:

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
| id | data       | totale | sconti | annulli | resi | sf |
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
|  1 | 2016-03-01 | 153.82 |   1.07 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 34 |
|  2 | 2016-03-02 | 241.58 |   0.01 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 32 |
|  3 | 2016-03-03 |   0.00 |   0.01 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
|  4 | 2016-03-04 |   0.00 |   0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
|  5 | 2016-03-05 |   0.00 |   0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
```

The second table is like the one below and it's called `emergenza`:

```
+----+------------+----------+--------+
| id | data       | ora      | totale |
+----+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | 2016-03-04 | 09:30:00 |   2.20 |
|  2 | 2016-03-04 | 09:40:00 |   9.00 |
|  3 | 2016-03-04 | 09:50:00 |   5.00 |
|....|............|..........|........|
| 27 | 2016-03-05 | 09:14:00 |   4.40 |
| 28 | 2016-03-05 | 09:27:00 |   5.00 |
| 29 | 2016-03-05 | 09:33:00 |   2.20 |
|....|............|..........|........|
+----+------------+----------+--------+
```

What I find difficult here is that in the `emergenza` table there are multiple row with the same date. In another view (`view_emergenza`) I grouped them by date in this way:

```
SELECT
    data,
    sum(totale) AS chiusura,
    count(id) AS sf

FROM emergenza

GROUP BY DAY(data);
```

The result is:

```
+------------+----------+----+
| data       | chiusura | sf |
+------------+----------+----+
| 2016-03-04 |   178.90 | 26 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 | 52 |
| 2016-03-06 |   333.55 | 46 |
| 2016-03-07 |   272.40 | 31 |
| 2016-03-08 |   169.40 | 28 |
| 2016-03-09 |   223.40 | 20 |
| 2016-03-10 |   206.00 | 19 |
| 2016-03-11 |   157.50 | 22 |
+------------+----------+----+
```

Moreover I need to perform some math before summing the two table. In a view (`view_chiusure`) I perfomed this kind of math to achieve the wanted results:

```
SELECT data, (totale - annulli - resi) AS chiusura, sf
    FROM chiusure
```

The result is:

```
+------------+----------+----+
| data       | chiusura | sf |
+------------+----------+----+
| 2016-03-01 |   153.82 | 34 |
| 2016-03-02 |   241.58 | 32 |
| 2016-03-03 |     0.00 |  0 |
| 2016-03-04 |     0.00 |  0 |
| 2016-03-05 |     0.00 |  0 |
+------------+----------+----+
```

At this point I want to merge the two views in one unique view:

- GROUP BY DAY(data) AS data
- (chiusure.totale - chiusure.annulli - chiusure.resi) + [sum(emergenza.totale) GROUP BY emergenza.data WHERE emergenza.data = chiusure.data]
- chiusure.sf + [count(emergenza.id) GROUP BY emergenza.data WHERE emergenza.data = chiusure.data]

**UPDATE**

I Tried in this way:

```
SELECT
        C.data,
        C.chiusura + (SELECT E.chiusura FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data ) AS chiusura,
        C.sf + (SELECT E.sf FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data ) as sf
    FROM view_chiusure C
```

but it seems that `view_chiusure.chiusura` and `view_chiusure.sf` are totally ignored

```
+------------+----------+------+
| data       | chiusura | sf   |
+------------+----------+------+
| 2016-03-01 |     NULL | NULL |
| 2016-03-02 |     NULL | NULL |
| 2016-03-03 |     NULL | NULL |
| 2016-03-04 |   178.90 |   26 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 |   52 |
| 2016-03-06 |   333.55 |   46 |
| 2016-03-07 |   272.40 |   31 |
| 2016-03-08 |   169.40 |   28 |
| 2016-03-09 |   223.40 |   20 |
| 2016-03-10 |   206.00 |   19 |
+------------+----------+------+
```

The result should be

```
+------------+----------+------+
| data       | chiusura | sf   |
+------------+----------+------+
| 2016-03-01 |   153.82 |   34 |
| 2016-03-02 |   241.58 |   42 |
| 2016-03-03 |     0.00 |    0 |
| 2016-03-04 |   178.90 |   26 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 |   52 |
| 2016-03-06 |   333.55 |   46 |
| 2016-03-07 |   272.40 |   31 |
| 2016-03-08 |   169.40 |   28 |
| 2016-03-09 |   223.40 |   20 |
| 2016-03-10 |   206.00 |   19 |
+------------+----------+------+
```

Is it possible to merge and sum the two tables? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server? You have tags for two different RDBMSs.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ MYSQL. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem was quite complicated, but searching around I've found out `ESISTS` and `CASE` that solved this issue.

The solution is:

```
SELECT
        C.data,
        (
            CASE
                WHEN
                    EXISTS (SELECT E.chiusura FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data) = 1
                        THEN (SELECT E.chiusura FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data)
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
        + C.chiusura AS chiusura
    FROM view_chiusure C
```

In the solutions above `view_emergenza` will override `view_chiusure` instead of summing the two tables. This is still unclear to me why.

**EXISTS** checks if the query returns some value. Since **EXISTS** returns booleans (true, false; 1, 0), I had to check if the row was matched. Here comes **CASE** in help.

So if the row is matched, it will perform the **SELECT** and return the wanted value, **ELSE** it has to return 0.

Eventually I will add the result to the first table column.

This is the result:

```
+------------+----------+
| data       | chiusura |
+------------+----------+
| 2016-03-01 |   153.82 |
| 2016-03-02 |   241.58 |
| 2016-03-03 |     0.00 |
| 2016-03-04 |   178.90 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 |
+------------+----------+
```

To make some tests I updated the originary table `chiusure`

```
UPDATE chiusure SET totale = 50 WHERE data = "2016-03-04";
```

Initially it was 0.

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
| id | data       | totale | sconti | annulli | resi | sf |
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
|  1 | 2016-03-01 | 153.82 |   1.07 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 34 |
|  2 | 2016-03-02 | 241.58 |   0.01 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 32 |
|  3 | 2016-03-03 |   0.00 |   0.01 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
|  4 | 2016-03-04 |  50.00 |   0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
|  5 | 2016-03-05 |   0.00 |   0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 |  0 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+---------+------+----+
```

`view_emergenza` is still the same:

```
+------------+----------+----+
| data       | chiusura | sf |
+------------+----------+----+
| 2016-03-04 |   178.90 | 26 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 | 52 |
| 2016-03-06 |   333.55 | 46 |
| 2016-03-07 |   272.40 | 31 |
| 2016-03-08 |   169.40 | 28 |
+------------+----------+----+
```

then in the new view the result is:

```
+------------+----------+
| data       | chiusura |
+------------+----------+
| 2016-03-01 |   153.82 |
| 2016-03-02 |   241.58 |
| 2016-03-03 |     0.00 |
| 2016-03-04 |   228.90 |
| 2016-03-05 |   330.55 |
+------------+----------+
```

The same is applied with the column **sf**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an artificial column to each select in the union to prevent losing matching rows.

Assuming the 2 selects you wish to aggregate work as you indicate, this should work:

```
select 'data' as data, 
       sum(chiusura) as chiusura, 
       sum(sf) as sf from
(
    SELECT 1 as col, chiusure.`data`, (chiusure.totale - chiusure.annulli - chiusure.resi) AS chiusura, chiusure.sf
    FROM chiusure

    UNION
    SELECT 2 as col, emergenza.`data`, emergenza.totale as chiusura, count(emergenza.id) as sf
    FROM emergenza
) tables
group by 'data'
```

Comment: it shows the error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Answer (score 0):

You must create views `view_emergenza` and `view_chiusure` at first.
Then you must create a view to get dates only:

```
CREATE VIEW vu_data AS
  (
  SELECT data FROM view_chiusure
  UNION
  SELECT data FROM view_emergenza
  )
```

Then create a view to get distinct dates:

```
CREATE VIEW vu_distinct_data AS
  SELECT DISTINCT data
  FROM vu_data
```

Now you can create another view to join the base views as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW vu_join AS
  SELECT
    (SELECT C.chiusura FROM view_chiusura C WHERE C.data=D.data)+
    (SELECT E.chiusura FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data=D.data) AS chiusura,
    (SELECT C.sf FROM view_chiusura C WHERE C.data=D.data)+
    (SELECT E.sf FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data=D.data) AS sf,
    D.data
  FROM vu_distinct_data D
```

Now you can easily use the `vu_join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM vu_join
ORDER BY data
```

Comment: Basically I need to create 5 views to get the wanted results?

Comment: Yes, this is because some dates may don't appear in one of the 2 tables and appear in other one.

Comment: if all dates will appear in both tables we can write it in one view.

Comment: That's not the case, since emergenza is not always used every day like chiusure. I'll give it a try

Comment: Ok, so you must create 3 views as I answered.

Comment: It seems that in this way view_emergenze.chiusura will overwrite view_chiusure.chiusura!

NULL | NULL | 2016-03-01

Comment: Logic of my answer is adding `chiusura` from 2 views for every date and also adding `sf` from 2 views for every date not overwriting.

Comment: Still doen't work. Your trick can also be achieved in one view:


SELECT
 C.data,
 C.chiusura + ( SELECT E.chiusura FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data ) AS chiusura,
 C.sf + (SELECT E.sf FROM view_emergenza E WHERE E.data = C.data )
 
 FROM view_chiusure C

Comment: `view_chiusure` is written by you. If not working correct it.
You must notice the logic of my queries not face of them. If you understand the logic, you can change it when needed.

Comment: Well, it works. As stated in the question. So it musn't be correct. However I've found out the solution. The results won't show because I needed to use an IF statement to check if they existed in the first place

Comment: Please send your final solution as a new answer.

Comment: Have to wait two days